# knitr does not embed image plots

Tags: r, knitr, r-markdown

I'm using `knitr` and `markdown` in a Script like this:

```
library(knitr)
library(markdown)
knit("myfile.Rmd", output="out.md")
markdownToHTML("out.md", output="result.html")
```

the final result file "result.html" looks good except that the images from plots are not diplayed.

In the source of the html file the images are referred to as:

```
<p><img src="figure/unnamed-chunk-16-1.png" alt="plot of chunk unnamed-chunk-16"/> </p>
```

and not self-contained. The referred image file does not exist.

I'm on a linux machine with R 3.1.2 and all packages are up to date.
I installed the `httpuv` and the `caTools` package but nothing changed.

here is a minimal Rmd file

````
---
title: "test"
output: html_document
---

all the packages that I'm loading    

```{r}
library(lattice)
library(caret)
library(nnet)
library(pROC)
library(VIM)
```

plot that does not work

```{r}
attach(iris)
xyplot(iris$Sepal.Length~iris$Sepal.Width)
```
````

Comment: Can you provide a minimal example of a knitr .Rmd that yields this problem? It's hard to help without seeing the source.

Comment: I cannot reproduce your example. The plot is displayed as it should be. Using `knitr_1.9` and `markdown_0.7.4` on windows.

Comment: @shadow here is how it looks for me:  http://i.imgur.com/uD3tyfH.png